# Mongoose updateOne with parameter {new:true} not showing actual updated value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am struggling for a couple of hours to show the final value of an updated document (via mongoose **updateOne**). I successfully modify it as I can see "nModified: 1" when I call the endpoint on Postman, but I am not able to output the actual final document - even when using the parameter ***{new:true}***

This is the code for the route:

```
// 3. We check if blockid is in this project
        Block.findById(req.params.blockid)
          .then(block => {
            if (!block) {
              errors.noblock = "Block not found";
              return res.status(404).json(errors);
            }

            // 4. We found the block, so we modify it
            Block.updateOne(
              { _id: req.params.blockid },
              { $set: blockFields },   // data to be updated
              { new: true },           // flag to show the new updated document
              (err, block) => {
                if (err) {
                  errors.noblock = "Block not found";
                  return res.status(404).json(errors);
                }
                console.log(block);
                res.json(block);
              }
            );
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Instead, this is the output I am getting (Mongoose is on debug mode)

[image: Mongoose output]

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 12):

`{ new : true }` will return the modified document rather than the original. `updateOne` doesn't have this option. If you need response as updated document use `findOneAndUpdate`.

Below are the [mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) function where you can use `{ new : true }`

- findByIdAndUpdate()
- findOneAndUpdate()
- findOneAndDelete()
- findOneAndRemove()
- findOneAndReplace()

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @sivasankar for the answer. Here is the updated working version with **findOneAndUpdate**

[image: mongoose new function findoneandupdate]

And here the expected result:

[image: terminal result outputting the document]

Answer (score 0):

you should give second param as object of keys value paris of data,
don't pass as $Set : blockfields, just add like below, if it is object containing parameters,

> { $set: blockFields }
>   Because code should be like this

```
Block.updateOne(
  { _id: req.params.blockid },
  blockFields, // if blockfields is object containing parameters
  { new: true },
  (err, block) => {
    // lines of code
  }
);
```

For more detail here is link to updateOne function detail [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne)

Comment: blockFields are the parameters to be updated. {new:true} is a flag for outputting mongoose results, but its not showing the new result. I will edit the description.

Comment: ok, if "blockFields" itself is an object containing parameters then don't write it as you are writing i am updating my solution check it.